# Fetching a 2 dimensional array from a 3 dimensional array in Arduino

Tags: arrays, random, multidimensional-array, arduino

I'm currently trying to assign to a 2-D array from a 3-D array using the random function. As such:

```
byte blocks[7][4][2] = {{{0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0}}};
byte currentBlock[4][2] = blocks[random(0,6)];
```

I get "error: invalid array assignment" when trying to compile.

Why does it do this and how can I achieve what I want? I understand there's only one thing in my 3-D array, but I'd rather not waste my time entering the rest if I can't do this.

Thanks!

**Bump**

**Second bump**

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and stuff. I have found, what seems to be a solution. To use `memcpy`

```
  memcpy(blocks[currentBlock, random(0,6)], sizeof(blocks[k]));
```

Seems to do the trick. Unfortunately that only counts for compiling, I don't know if it will run fine as I don't have my arduino on me, but I'll use this as the accepted answer if it works ok.

Comment: You've got the source and destination the wrong way round; i.e. swap `blocks[random(0,6)]` with `currentBlock`.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the contents of the array doesn't seem like the best approach for most purposes (unless you specifically need an independent copy which you can modify without affecting the original).

Generally speaking, a better approach is to store a pointer to the part of the array you want to use. For example:

```
byte blocks[7][4][2] = {{{0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0}}, ... };
byte (*currentBlock)[2] = blocks[random(0, 6)];
```

That will make `currentBlock` point to a random 4x2 array within `blocks`. You would access it in exactly the same way as a regular array. The only difference is that any changes you make using `currentBlock` will affect `blocks` as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to be able to change the contents of `currentBlock`. I want to be able to rotate the block.

Comment: When you say 'rotate', if you mean move it to point to a different block, then that's no problem. You can re-assign to pointer to a different part of the array without affecting anything else. The only thing you need to be aware of is that any changes to the actual values themselves will affect `blocks` as well.

Comment: No, I mean physically change the values so it's rotated. I'm doing a Tetris clone for a custom arduino shield. So it needs to rotate the actual pixels. Worst comes to worst, I'll need to store each possible position of the rotations to save time, but it might take too much space.